# Entity Framework - How to update fields from a list of key-value pairs?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Let's say the user modifies his profile record that contains fields such as FirstName, LastName, Email, etc.

For each field that is modified, the change is stored as a key-value pair in a list of type:

```
List<Tuple<string, object>>
```

The key in this key-value pair represents the actual table column.

While trying to update the record, here is one way to do it:

```
foreach (Tuple<string, object> field in changeList) {
    if (field.Item1.equals("FirstName")) {
        user.FirstName = field.Item2;
    }
    if (field.Item1.equals("Email")) {
       user.Email = field.Item2;
    }
    ...
}

db.SaveChanges()
```

I am thinking there must be a better way to accomplish this.

I guess I could use reflection to set each property on the user

```
foreach(tuple<string, object> field in changeList) {
  user.GetType().InvokeMember(field.Item1,
     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
     Type.DefaultBinder, user, field.Item2);    
}
```

I am wondering if there is even better way. Perhaps I could build a "var" object dynamically that will also let me use TryUpdateModel() method.

Comment: How did those values get into a `List<tuple<string, object>>` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar but using a custom object of type string and object.  I also don't know if this is the efficient one but it gets the job done. To demonstrate I have used Tuple where first item1 is string and item2 is an object.

```
List<Tuple<string, object>> listTuple = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();

listTuple.Add(new Tuple<string, object>("FirstName", "Foo"));
listTuple.Add(new Tuple<string, object>("LastName", "Bar"));


PropertyInfo[] props = user.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
      if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "ICollection`1")
      {
        //Do not do anything these are navigation properties in entity framework.
        //For eg. If User has Applications then do not set values for Applications.
      }
      else
        {
                //Match each property with matching Item1 in Tuple.
            var myTuple = listTuple.Where(x => x.Item1 == prop.Name).First();
            //Set Users Property using myTuple's Item2 which is an object here. 
            prop.SetValue(user, myTuple.Item2, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the old pal ADO.NET.

The other way is [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

**Edit**

Sorry, I Think Dynamic LINQ can only be used for filtering. May be ADO.NET is the best option. I'm out of ideas.