# How to dynamically build properties on an object

Tags: .net, dynamic

It appears, the new "dynamic" object let's you create properties on the fly:

```
dynamic v = new object();
v.x = "a";
v.y = "b";
...
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to programatically create properties. For example, let's say my properties are stored in a list as follows:

```
Tuple<string, string>[] list = new Tuple<string, string>[] {
  new Tuple<string, string>("x", "a"),
  new Tuple<string, string>("y", "b"),
};
```

I would like to iterate through this list and achieve the same result as we did earlier.

```
dynamic v = new object();
foreach (Tuple<string, string> keyValue in list) {
    // somehow create a property on v that is named keyValue.Item1 and has a value KeyValue.Item2            
}
```

I am wondering if this is even possible.

Comment: You can only "add properties" if the object supports it... and the `Object` type doesn't so it won't work in this case.

Comment: If this question is related to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349285/entity-framework-how-to-update-fields-from-a-list-of-key-value-pairs) then ExpandoObject is not the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Your initial code is incorrect. It will fail at execution time. If you use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) instead, *then* it will work - and *then* you can do it programmatically as well, using the fact that `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`. It implements it with explicit interface implementation, however, so you need to have an expression of that type first. For example:

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = d;
dictionary["key"] = "value";
Console.WriteLine(d.key); // Prints "value"
```

Or for your example:

```
dynamic v = new ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = v;
foreach (Tuple<string, string> keyValue in list)
{
    dictionary[keyValue.Item1] = keyValue.Item2;
}
```

I'd personally use `KeyValuePair` rather than `Tuple` for this by the way - because that's what you've got here.

Comment: I think you meant `d.key`, rather than `dictionary.key`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: Yup - fixed.